# Successfully submitted form but one error in console, like A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048 - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, date

When I submit my form successfully inserting all data in the table, as well as getting an error in console like below,  Is there any problem in code?, I have found unusual date in the error, date is showing '1970-01-01'. But I picked today's date, But in error its shows only '1970-01-01';

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'purchase_shopId' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `stock_purchase_history` (`purchase_shopId`, `purchase_productID`, `purchase_quantity`, `purchase_costPrice`, `purchase_TotalRate`, `purchase_tax`, `purchase_taxEmp`, `purchase_sellingPrice`, `purchase_employeeSellingPrice`, `purchase_supplierName`, `purchase_invoice`, `purchase_PurchaseDate`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, '1970-01-01')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/stock/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

my query code

```
public function insertPurchaseData()
    {
         $shopId =  $this->input->post('shopId');
         $productID =  $this->input->post('productID');
         $quantity =  $this->input->post('quantity');
         $costPrice =  $this->input->post('costPrice');         
         $PurchaseTotalRate = $quantity*$costPrice;
         $taxNormal =  $this->input->post('taxNormal'); 
         $taxEmp =  $this->input->post('taxEmp');
         $supplierName =  $this->input->post('supplierName');
         $invoice =  $this->input->post('invoice');
         $PurchaseDate =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('PurchaseDate')));        
         //  normal Selling price
         $sellingPrice=($costPrice*$taxNormal)/100+$costPrice ;

         //  emp selling price
         $employeeSellingPrice=($costPrice*$taxEmp)/100+$costPrice;

        $purchaseData =array(

            'purchase_shopId'               => $shopId,                  
            'purchase_productID'            => $productID, 
            'purchase_quantity'             =>$quantity,
            'purchase_costPrice'            =>$costPrice,
            'purchase_TotalRate'            =>$PurchaseTotalRate,
            'purchase_tax'                  =>$taxNormal,
            'purchase_taxEmp'                  =>$taxEmp,
            'purchase_sellingPrice'         =>$sellingPrice,
            'purchase_employeeSellingPrice'=>$employeeSellingPrice,
            'purchase_supplierName'         =>$supplierName,
            'purchase_invoice'               =>$invoice,
            'purchase_PurchaseDate'         =>$PurchaseDate

            );
            $this->db->insert('stock_purchase_history',$purchaseData);



    }
```

see below ajax code

```
      if(result == '1234567')
    {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Con_purchase/add_purchase_for_shop')?>",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { 
                    shopId: shopId,
                    productID: productID,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    costPrice : costPrice ,
                    taxNormal : taxNormal ,
                    taxEmp : taxEmp ,                       
                    supplierName : supplierName, 
                    invoice  : invoice , 
                    PurchaseDate   : PurchaseDate  
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {              if (data == '1') {
                            var btn = $(this).closest("tr")
                            var name = inputData.find("button").prop('disabled', false).css(
                            "background-color", "green"); 
                    } else {
                            var btn = $(this).closest("tr")
                            var name = inputData.find("button").prop('disabled', true).css(
                            "background-color", "#2d7bf4");

                    }
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

my db
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jZ9z.png)

Comment: var_dump your post array and check whether your data pass to controller correctly.
var_dump($this->input->post());

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your column structure to null `'purchase_shopId'` because you have checked checkbox for null.

Answer (score 0):

Column 'purchase_shopId' cannot be null, you can change in the Database 'purchase_shopId' can be null.

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
ALTER COLUMN `purchase_shopId` varchar(20) 
DEFAULT NULL
```